# re-mount two old disk from raid0 setup to recover data

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I had setup two 500gb disk in RAID0 on my server, but recently suffered a hard disk failure (saw a S.M.A.R.T error on the HDD at boot). My host has put 2 new disk in RAID-0 again (re-installed the OS) and re-attached the old drives on the same machine, so that I can recover the data.

My old drives are:

**/dev/sdb**
and
**/dev/sdc**

How can I mount these two disks back in RAID0, so that we can recover the data from our old drive? Or is this not possible any more? Have I lost all my data?

This is my **/etc/fstab** and **df -h**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xBgz.png

This is my **fdisk -l**: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=68puYEXD

Any help/tips/advice regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is more appropriate to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) and you will likely get better/more answers there.

Comment: I did some searching and found that you can "assemble" the array using this command: mdadm -A --scan, however there is no luck as per this result -> http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uc2QieQS

Comment: The short answer is: Don't be too hopeful.  Raid 0 has _no_ fault tolerance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. I have posted this on ServerFault and SuperUser.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: please don't cross-post. This question will probably be moved to superuser, unless you delete it.